# Controlling the master speaker volume in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, volume, delphi-2007

I have a written a very simple application that I use to play my music collection with in Delphi 2007 that runs on Windows 7. I shell out to the Windows Media Player to avoid the Delphi Media Player component which refuses to play some tracks that I throw at it. I would now like to control the volume of the speaker from the application.

At this point I say 'speaker volume' rather than 'WMP volume' because I imagine controlling the volume of the WMP is more difficult than controlling the overall speaker/master volume for all applications.

I'm sure this was very simple in the past but OS get more complex and all the code snippets that I have found and tried don't work for the master/core volume that controls the speakers.

Is it possible to control this master volume from a Delphi 2007 running on Windows 7?

If it is, then a couple of functions like GetVolume and SetVolume I could use to do what is such a basic task would be very much appreciated.

I have looked at similar questions asked in the past and I am not hopeful.

Bruce.

Comment: The Delphi version is mentioned twice in the question, @Tlama, but I fail to see how it's so relevant that it needs to be included in the tags. Do you think a different version would call for different answers?

Comment: @Rob, ah, sorry. Taking back. I was asking because of possible difference in type library imports... (even if there shouldn't be, I know). But never mind, I don't have a time for this Q anymore.

Comment: Could it be the same as [setting the volume in Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/03/06/how-do-i-change-the-master-volume-in-windows-vista.aspx)?

Comment: @Rob, yes, but I would prefer [`an example`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/dd370839(v=vs.85).aspx) from MS. There are also some Delphi translations, e.g. the [`MFPack`](https://code.google.com/p/mfpack-media-foundation/) with [`this unit`](http://mfpack-media-foundation.googlecode.com/svn-history/r26/MF/SAMPLES/Win78Mixer.pas), but I just don't believe to any code whose author can't even follow proper code formatting.

Answer (score 7):

Under Windows 7 you must use the [Core Audio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to control the Windows audio. from here you can try the [IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the [IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMasterVolumeLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Try this code which uses the `SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar` method.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

const
  CLASS_IMMDeviceEnumerator : TGUID = '{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}';
  IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator : TGUID = '{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}';
  IID_IAudioEndpointVolume : TGUID = '{5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A}';

type
  IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{657804FA-D6AD-4496-8A60-352752AF4F89}']
  end;

  IAudioEndpointVolume = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A}']
    function RegisterControlChangeNotify(AudioEndPtVol: IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UnregisterControlChangeNotify(AudioEndPtVol: IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetChannelCount(out PInteger): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetMasterVolumeLevel(fLevelDB: single; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(fLevelDB: single; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMasterVolumeLevel(out fLevelDB: single): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMasterVolumeLevelScaler(out fLevelDB: single): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetChannelVolumeLevel(nChannel: Integer; fLevelDB: double; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(nChannel: Integer; fLevelDB: double; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetChannelVolumeLevel(nChannel: Integer; out fLevelDB: double): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(nChannel: Integer; out fLevel: double): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetMute(bMute: Boolean; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMute(out bMute: Boolean): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVolumeStepInfo(pnStep: Integer; out pnStepCount: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function VolumeStepUp(pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function VolumeStepDown(pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function QueryHardwareSupport(out pdwHardwareSupportMask): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVolumeRange(out pflVolumeMindB: double; out pflVolumeMaxdB: double; out pflVolumeIncrementdB: double): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IAudioMeterInformation = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064}']
  end;

  IPropertyStore = interface(IUnknown)
  end;

  IMMDevice = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F}']
    function Activate(const refId: TGUID; dwClsCtx: DWORD;  pActivationParams: PInteger; out pEndpointVolume: IAudioEndpointVolume): HRESULT; stdCall;
    function OpenPropertyStore(stgmAccess: DWORD; out ppProperties: IPropertyStore): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetId(out ppstrId: PLPWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetState(out State: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;


  IMMDeviceCollection = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E}']
  end;

  IMMNotificationClient = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{7991EEC9-7E89-4D85-8390-6C703CEC60C0}']
  end;

  IMMDeviceEnumerator = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}']
    function EnumAudioEndpoints(dataFlow: TOleEnum; deviceState: SYSUINT; DevCollection: IMMDeviceCollection): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDF: SYSUINT; ER: SYSUINT; out Dev :IMMDevice ): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDevice(pwstrId: pointer; out Dev: IMMDevice): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(pClient: IMMNotificationClient): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

procedure SetMasterVolume(fLevelDB: single);
var
  pEndpointVolume: IAudioEndpointVolume;
  LDeviceEnumerator: IMMDeviceEnumerator;
  Dev: IMMDevice;
begin
  if not Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_IMMDeviceEnumerator, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, LDeviceEnumerator)) then
   RaiseLastOSError;
  if not Succeeded(LDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint($00000000, $00000000, Dev)) then
   RaiseLastOSError;

  if not Succeeded( Dev.Activate(IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, nil, pEndpointVolume)) then
   RaiseLastOSError;

  if not Succeeded(pEndpointVolume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(fLevelDB, nil)) then
   RaiseLastOSError;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      SetMasterVolume(1.0); //set the volume to the max
      Sleep(2000);
      SetMasterVolume(0.5); //set the volume to the 50 %
      Sleep(2000);
      SetMasterVolume(0.1); //set the volume to the 10 %
      Sleep(2000);
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```